# Scatter-plot: Change circle radius interactively

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I have a scatter-plot in bokeh and I want the user to be able to change the radious of all the circles of the plot with a Slider, interactively.

Until now I have only managed to have this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.layouts import column
import pandas as pd

radius = 0.3
source = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 5], [3, 4]], columns=['a','b']) 
p = figure()
p.scatter(x='a', y='b', source=source, radius=radius)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(radius=radius), code="""
        var radius = cb_obj.get('value');
        source.trigger('change');
    """)

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=1.0, value=0.3, step=.05, title="Circle-radius", callback=callback)
layout = column(p, slider)
show(layout)
```

but circle radius doesn't change when I change the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the value of the slider into a local JavaScript variable, but then don't actually use it for anything. To affect the glyph, you would actually need to set some property of the glyph, or update the data the drives the glyph. To do that, you can pass *Bokeh objects* in the `args` dict (it does not usually make sense to pass plain python values as you have done).

Additionally, the `.get` syntax was removed a long time ago, unless you are using an ancient version of Bokeh, you should be using `cb_obj.value`.

Here is a complete example tested with Bokeh > 1.0

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.layouts import column
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 5], [3, 4]], columns=['a','b'])
p = figure()
r = p.circle(x='a', y='b', source=source, radius=0.3)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(renderer=r), code="""
    renderer.glyph.radius = cb_obj.value;
""")

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=1.0, value=0.3, step=.05, title="Circle-radius")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

show(column(p, slider))
```

Finally, although the `callback` property is still supported for Bokeh 1.x, it will be deprecated soon. New code should use the general `js_on_change` method shown above.

[image]